# Converting Excel Date/Time to 24-hour with missing characters

Tags: excel

I received a sheet with thousands of records where the date/time records are incorrect.  Some of the time format is missing a leading zero, and I need to trim off the AM/PM and seconds places.  Time time needs to be in 24-hour (military) time. Ex:

```
10/8/2016  80000 AM
Should be:  2016-10-08 08:00   (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm)
```

Some of the other records have the correct amount of characters. Ex:

```
10/8/2016  120000 PM
Should be:  2016-10-08 12:00    (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm)
```

Therefore, I can just trim the PM and seconds from the right.

General rule:  If the number begins with a 1 it is likely a time between 10:00 and 19:59, if the number begins with a 2 - 9 likely just add a 0 in front and making it 02:00 through 09:59.

My challenge is finding a formula that will accomplish all of this so I don't have to wade through thousands of records to fix the time.

Comment: Is the date separated from the time by a double space in each entry? If so, a starting point is to separate out the date with `=LEFT(A1, FIND("   ", A1))`. Excel will accept a date with a single-digit month or day.

Comment: Some of the separation is two spaces or three spaces.  My apologies for leaving that out.

Comment: Update:  I can remove the time, and format it so the spaces are removed, and leading spaces are removed.  Now, I need to write an IF function that says (in plain English): If the first character begins with a 1, do nothing.  If it begins with a 2- 9, add a leading zero.  This will solve my problem.  Then I can concatenate the date with the properly formatted time.

Comment: Update:  I figured this out.  I couldn't do it all in a single formula, but I was able to get there.  Thanks for the assistance @jsheeran!
=IF(LEFT(AE2,1)="1",AE2,"0"&AE2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have already figured this out but here is one approach (just because I found it interesting)
[image]

So column **A** holds the actual value
Column **C** has the following formula to extract the date (presumption here is that first part of the string in column **A** is a date):

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ", A2, 1)-1), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Column **D** extracts the time string from column **A**:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2)),SEARCH(" ", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2)))-1)
```

Now to convert the value in column **D** to a 24hour time format (without the `:`) based on **`AM`** or **`PM`** in column **A**. So column **E** is:

```
=IF(UPPER(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),2))="PM",IF(LEFT(TRIM(D2),1)="1",12+INT(LEFT(D2,2)),12+INT(LEFT(D2,1)))&RIGHT(TRIM(D2),4), D2)
```

All that is left is to create the required string.. that's where column **F** comes in:

```
=C2& " "&IF(LEN(E2)=5,"0"&LEFT(E2,1),LEFT(E2,2))&":"&IF(LEN(E2)=5,MID(E2, 2,2),MID(E2, 3,2))
```

Not sure if this is the best approach but first one that came to my head :)

Comment: Marking as the answer.  This was almost the exact same path I took to fix it.